# Kendo html editor

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, kendo-ui, html-editor

I have a kendo html editor. And in the body I have a default text. So if you load the html kendoeditor then the default text will be shown.

It looks like this:

```
public class EmailTemplateController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Salaris/EmailTemplate
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(EmailTemplate model)
    {
        model.EmailContent = "Nieuwe inhoud...";
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        // return View();
    }
}
```

and I have the view like this:

```
@model SDB.Models.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplate

<div id="emailContent">
    <div class="property full">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmailContent, "HtmlEditorEmailTemplate")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailContent)
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/EmailTemplate/Index",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "json",
            data: placeMarker,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {                    

                }
                else {
                    //do something
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the model:

```
public class EmailTemplate
{
    public string EmailContent { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that if I run the view. I see the message: Nieuwe inhoud...

But I only see the text. So the kendo htmleditor is not shown anymore.

This is how it has to be:

[image]

But I see it like this:

[image]

Comment: This whole thing really doesn't make a lot of sense. It's hard to know what you exactly want to do here. You've an Index method which accepts a GET request and returns JSON, but returns an empty object (`data` is not defined in your C# method, I'm surprised it even compiles TBH). Then you have a view (is it index or something else?) which has a template for an EmailTemplate object, but it's not clear where you're returning that object. Then you have an ajax call to this "Index" C# method, but it sends a POST instead of a GET (so can't be working) and also will ignore the response it gets.

Comment: Based the code above, it's hard to see how you've got anything working at all, or how you could possibly be getting the "Nieuwe inhoud..." message on screen, unless this is also populated from another source you haven't shown. Can you check your code and ensure that it actually reproduces your problem. Like I said, your C# method as shown won't even compile because `data` is not defined.

Comment: HI, thank you for your answare. I edit the post . My mistake it was model

Comment: Ok. Well you can't populate a razor template from JSON. To populate that you need to return a View or a Partial View (depending on the circumstances). Are you trying to use ajax to fetch JSON data and build the HTML client-side, or are you trying to use Views and Razor to generate the HTML? You need to make up your mind. Also at the moment your ajax call doesn't do anything. The C# code now will, in itself, work, but your example still isn't very clear.

Comment: @ADyson. I update the post

Comment: Yes, like I said, you can't use JSON to populate a Razor template. You need to be returning a View object containing your model. It's not clear why you tried to use JSON for this.

Comment: Because I want to have the text: Nieuwe inhoud... in de Kendo html editor. as default.

Comment: that doesn't require JSON. If you want to use a Razor template as you've shown, then it requires you setting the model property, which you do correctly, and then returning `View(model);` instead of `Json(model...etc`. In other words, just do the thing you normally do with an MVC model and view. There's no need here to mess about with JSON at all. Again, it's not clear to me why you thought this was necessary or workable. Is this your first time using MVC? Have you taken an introductory tutorial which would show you a basic example of how to do this?

Comment: HI, I just solved.

Comment: That's good. I guess it was as per my answer? If so please remember to mark it accepted for future readers, or otherwise answer it yourself showing what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

with

```
return View(model);
```

There's no need to use JSON at all here, it won't work to populate a Razor template. Instead you must return a view (or partial view) for that to work.

You can also remove your $.ajax code, because it doesn't do anything useful.